# Proving that $n\sin^{n}{n} \leq \sqrt{n^{2} + 2n}$

Tags: inequality, proof-verification

I need to prove $n\sin^{n}{n} \leq \sqrt{n^{2} + 2n}$ to show I have an upper bound for something. At least I think it is true, but I'm not sure if I showed it correctly. (for $n >0$).

My try:

Note that $n^{2}\sin^{2n}{n} > 0$, and that $\sin^{2n}{n} < 1$.

Then $n^{2}\sin^{2n}{n} \leq n^{2} < n^{2} + 2n$. Then we just take the square root, and we have our result. Is this reasonable?

Comment: Looks good, but note that $\sqrt{n^2\sin^{2n}n}\neq n\sin^n n$.

Comment: @QuangHoang OP posted $n^2 sin^{2n} n$, not $n sin^{2n} n$

Comment: @QuangHoang Oh right because $\pm$. Does that affect the inequality at all when I take the square root of both sides though?

Comment: no, it doesn't: $x\le |x|=\sqrt{x^2}$ always.

Comment: Just an observation, but for positive integer $n$, $n\sin^n(n)$ is clearly less than $n$ right? Since $\sin$ only achieves $\pm1$ at certain multiples of $\pi/2$? And in turn, $n$ is clearly less than $\sqrt{n^2+2n}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $n$ is restricted to be positive, $n = \sqrt{n^2} < \sqrt{n^2+2n}$. Following your observation about sine, this should check out just fine.

Answer (score 0):

$\sin(n)^n$ is bounded between $1$ and $-1$, so it's safe to say that

$$-1<\sin(n)^n<1 <n^2+2n$$

Now just multiply by $n^2$ and take the square root.